# Set Android View background image efficiently gives java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, bitmap, background, drawable

In the process of setting a background image to an Android View (API 22) I am facing some problems.

My image is a 1MB .jpeg file, 4000x2672.

At first I tried via the

```
android:background="@drawable/your_image"
```

method, getting an ***D/skia﹕ --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap*** error.

Then I followed http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html and implemented it as follows:

BitmapDecoder.java

```
(..omissis..)
public class BitmapDecoder {

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

}

SplasActivity.java (the main activity)

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    LinearLayout mL = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.MainLayout);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),
                BitmapDecoder.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.andromeda,
                        1080,1920));
        mL.setBackground(d);
    }

    this.getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
```

I am getting WxH of the Device's screen, resizing the Drawable resource to that size, converting the resulting Bitmap to a Drawable, setting the Drawable as the View background.

But I always get the

> D/skia﹕ --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
>   ...
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 684032012 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 227MB until OOM

error.

I have been searching for hours now and implemented all suggested techniques with no luck.

As a side note, if I put as width and height a very small value (e.g. 400x200), it works. But, as you may imagine, that is not feasible.

Any idea on how to solve?

Comment: you want to allocate 684 MB for an image? post the stacktrace from the logcat, what does `calculateInSampleSize` return?

Comment: stacktrace from logcat: http://pastebin.com/2nxTDjLb

Comment: calculateInSampleSize returns 1, screen resolution is 1440 x 2560 (Samsung Galaxy S6)

Comment: place your jpeg in res/drawable-nodpi folder and see what happens

Comment: Bingo! that was the problem. Putting it in the drawable folder made Android assume it as a mdpi drawable, thus enlarging it multiple times before it was passed to decodeSampledBitmapFromResource. thanks.

Comment: exactly 16 times = 4 * 4 since 4 = xxxhdpi / mdpi, am i right you are using xxxhdpi?

Comment: yes I should as the screen is QHD. if you'd like add that as an answer so that I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

judging from your numbers you have placed your jpeg in `res/drawable` folder which is the same as `res/drawable-mdpi`, the remedy is to place it in `res/drawable-nodpi` folder

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you evaluate the image size in its compressed jpeg format (1MB) but when you load it and manipulate into your software it's unpacked in it's bitmap form.

As reported in the link you mentioned:
"... The lower resolution version should match the size of the UI component that displays it. An image with a higher resolution does not provide any visible benefit, but still takes up precious memory and incurs additional performance overhead due to additional on the fly scaling.
.."

You are using a 4000x2672= 10688000 pixels image, and each pixel requires a number of bytes to encode color, thus amounting the 684032012 allocated bytes.

The only suggestion I can give is to evaluate what is the bigger screen you want to show your image on, check it's definition and rescale your image so to match at most that value.

Comment: not necessarily, Actually I have not checked what is the actual amount of bytes used for color encoding, that's why I did not specify any other numeric value in my reply. Anyway part of the memory required is consumed to rescale and adapt the far-too-big image to the small screen. My aim was just to show that the image is bigger than needed, not investigating the details.

Comment: and that was the culprit. the size of the image actually used was not 4000x2672.